# How to calculate distance between two nodes in GraphX, Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph, spark-graphx

I want to calculate maximum distance between every node to sink node. Sink node being a node with no outer edges. I have found the function for shortest distance, but I want to know maximum distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate maximum distance between any two nodes in GraphX, you can use [Pregel API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#pregel-api)

The code can be like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx.{Graph, VertexId}
import org.apache.spark.graphx.util.GraphGenerators

// A graph with edge attributes containing distances
val graph: Graph[Long, Double] =
  GraphGenerators.logNormalGraph(sc, numVertices = 100).mapEdges(e => e.attr.toDouble)
val sourceId: VertexId = 42 // The ultimate source
// Initialize the graph such that all vertices except the root have distance infinity.
val initialGraph = graph.mapVertices((id, _) =>
    if (id == sourceId) 0.0 else Double.PositiveInfinity)
val sssp = initialGraph.pregel(Double.PositiveInfinity)(
  (id, dist, newDist) => math.max(dist, newDist), // Vertex Program
  triplet => {  // Send Message
    if (triplet.srcAttr + triplet.attr < triplet.dstAttr) {
      Iterator((triplet.dstId, triplet.srcAttr + triplet.attr))
    } else {
      Iterator.empty
    }
  },
  (a, b) => math.max(a, b) // Merge Message
)
println(sssp.vertices.collect.mkString("\n"))
```

Comment: Above answer will calculate the distance from one source node to multiple nodes as destination. Then we have to look for the destination node inside the sssp. 
But instead of doing this,  is it possible to calculate the distance from one source destination to  one destination only?, directly providing the source and destination i.e. 2 as source and 12 as destination.

Comment: is this possible using graphframes?

Comment: I have not looked at the GraphFrames for this application.